# Use same class for different checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, perl, checkbox

I have a multiselect dropdown which has 8 colors in a hash %all_colors:

```
my %all_colors = (
    1 => 'Red',
    2 => 'Yellow',
    3 => 'Orange',
    4 => 'Blue',
    5 => 'Black',
    6 => 'Brown',
    7 => 'Green',
    8 => 'White',
);
```

I have put it in a dropdown like this:

```
my $color_selector = '<select name="all_colors">';

foreach my $color (sort {$all_colors{$a} cmp $all_colors {$b}} keys %all_colors ) {
    $color_selector .= qq~<option value="$color">$all_colors{$color}</option>~;
}
$color_selector .= '</select>';

<div><% $color_selector %></div>
```

And in Perl, I added one more constant to select checkbox1 and use constant in perl to call the checkbox. And Rest of colors should be checked when clicked on "Rest of the Colors" checkbox.

```
use constant MAIN_COLORS => {
    1 => 'Red',
    2 => 'Orange',
    3 => 'Green',
    4 => 'White',
};

my $main_colors = MAIN_COLORS;
```

I have written a HTML code for checkbox and jQuery to select colors from dropdown on click of checkbox.

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="maincolors" name="colorcheckbox" value="<% $main_colors %>" class="inputCheckbox" /> Main Colors
    <input type="checkbox" data-class="restofcolors" name="colorcheckbox" class="inputCheckbox" /> Rest of the Colors
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('input[name="colorcheckbox"]').click(function () {
    var isselect       = '';
    var main_colors    = jQuery('input[data-class="main-colors"]').val().split('|');
    var colorsToSelect = jQuery(this).val();

    if (jQuery(this).prop('checked')) {
        isselect = 'selected';
    }

    if (jQuery(this).data('class') == 'main-colors') {
        for (var i=0; i < main_colors.length; i++) {
            jQuery('#allcolors option[value=' + main_colors[i] + ']').prop('selected', isselect);
        }
    } else {
        for (var i=0; i < jQuery('#allcolors option').length; i++){
            if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery('#allcolors option')[i].value, main_colors) < 0) {
                jQuery('#allcolors option')[i].selected = isselect;
            }
        }
    }

    if (jQuery(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        if (colorsToSelect == 'maincolors') {
            jQuery('#multipeColorSelect option').prop('selected', true);
        } else if (colorsToSelect == 'restofcolors') {
            jQuery('#multipeColorSelect option').prop('selected', true);
        }
    } else {
        if (colorsToSelect == 'maincolors') {
            jQuery('#multipeColorSelect option').prop('selected', false);
        } else if (colorsToSelect == 'restofcolors') {
            jQuery('#multipeColorSelect option').prop('selected', false);
        }
    }
  });

  jQuery('#allcolors').change(function() {
    jQuery('.inputCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

If I want to add one more checkbox in future which includes one of the main colors group, then I want to add a different class which is not a good idea. So my requirement is: For now for the above code, I dont want to use different classes "maincolors" and "restofcolors", instead want to solve this using the same class(only one class for all checkboxes). Please help.

Comment: I've put your code in a JSFiddle but it isn't working: http://jsfiddle.net/nj2b0bdr/  There are several errors in the code--did you check it before posting it here?

Comment: Yes, I checked but I am not able to find where I am going wrong.

Comment: It doesnt work in jsfiddle because there is perl code in there

Comment: It also doesn't work because there are numerous errors in the javascript code--e.g. the first line refers to `input[name="colorcheckbox"]`, but no such input exists in your code.

Comment: I corrected my code now in input checkbox

Comment: No. There is no third checkbox. When I do coding, I always imagine that if the code gets used in future and a third checkbox is added which includes one of the main colors group, then I need to change many places because there are different classes. Thats why I mentioned "one more checkbox". So my requirement is I dont want to use different classes "maincolors" and "restofcolors", instead want to solve this using the same class(only one class for all checboxes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your code extensible, you'll need to think of more general ways to approach the problem that you're trying to solve. If you're adding more checkboxes, you need to come up with a way to easily represent all the form data you'll need--the checkbox value, the label for the checkbox, and what combination of colours that grouping will represent:

```
my @color_data = (
   { value => 'main', title => 'Main Colors', colors => [ 1, 3, 7, 8 ] },
   { value => 'combo1', title => 'Combination 1', colors => [ 2, 4, 5, 6 ] },
   { value => 'combo2', title => 'Combination 2', colors => [ 1, 2, 3, 6 ] }
);
```

You can see that we have the data needed to create the form elements, and the `colors` array contains the IDs (from your hash `%all_colors`) of the colours in this combination. Now let's create the form:

```
# create the checkboxes using @color_data:
my $html = '';
for (@color_data) {
   $html .= "<input type='checkbox' name='colorcheckbox' value='" 
     . $_->{value} . "' id='colorcbox_" 
     . $_->{value} . "' />\n<label for='colorcbox_" 
     . $_->{value} . "'>" . $_->{title} . "</label>\n"
}
say $html;
```

This gives the output:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='colorcheckbox' value='main' id='colorcbox_main' />
<label for='colorcbox_main'>Main Colors</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='colorcheckbox' value='combo1' id='colorcbox_combo1' />
<label for='colorcbox_combo1'>Combination 1</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='colorcheckbox' value='combo2' id='colorcbox_combo2' />
<label for='colorcbox_combo2'>Combination 2</label>
```

Note that the text for each checkbox is surrounded by a `<label>` element: this makes the text clickable, and is the semantically-correct way to create checkbox labels. Each checkbox has an ID, which makes it easily targetable by javascript, and I've stripped the redundant `class="inputCheckbox"` -- if you're going to apply a class to all those checkboxes, it would be better to either apply the style globally (i.e. in your stylesheet for the page--set all checkboxes to display the same), or apply the style to the parent element of these checkboxes.

For the select element, I would advise you use the `data-class` attribute to capture information about which of the colour combinations the colour belongs to. You can do this in one (slightly complicated) statement by checking whether or not the colour ID exists in the array of colours for each grouping in `@color_data`:

```
for my $c (sort keys %all_colors) {
    $html .= "<option value='$all_colors{$c}' data-class='" 
    . join(" ", grep defined, 
        map { if (grep { $_ eq $c } @{$_->{colors}} ) { $_->{value} } else { } } @color_data) 
    . "'>$all_colors{$c}</option>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<option value='Red' data-class='main combo2'>Red</option>
<option value='Yellow' data-class='combo1 combo2'>Yellow</option>
<option value='Orange' data-class='main combo2'>Orange</option>
<option value='Blue' data-class='combo1'>Blue</option>
<option value='Black' data-class='combo1'>Black</option>
<option value='Brown' data-class='combo1 combo2'>Brown</option>
<option value='Green' data-class='main'>Green</option>
<option value='White' data-class='main'>White</option>
```

You can see that the `data-class` attribute contains the value of each entry in `@color_data` to which it belongs. The slightly complicated code does the following:

```
# join together the members of an array with a space
join(" ", 
# grep takes only the defined members of the array
grep defined,
# map: for every member of the array color_data
map { 
      # if $c exists in the array $_->{colors} (i.e. the list of colours)
      if (grep { $_ eq $c } @{$_->{colors}} )
      # output $_->{value} if it does ('main', 'combo1', 'combo2', etc)
      { $_->{value} } 
      # otherwise, output undefined (this has to be here or perl outputs '0')
      else { } 
} @color_data)
```

Here is the resulting form:

```
<fieldset>
<input type='checkbox' name='colorcheckbox' value='main' id='colorcbox_main' />
<label for='colorcbox_main'>Main Colors</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='colorcheckbox' value='combo1' id='colorcbox_combo1' />
<label for='colorcbox_combo1'>Combination 1</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='colorcheckbox' value='combo2' id='colorcbox_combo2' />
<label for='colorcbox_combo2'>Combination 2</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<label for='colorselect'>Pick some colours!</label>
<select name='all_colors' id='colorselect' multiple='multiple' size='8'>
<option value='Red' data-class='main combo2'>Red</option>
<option value='Yellow' data-class='combo1 combo2'>Yellow</option>
<option value='Orange' data-class='main combo2'>Orange</option>
<option value='Blue' data-class='combo1'>Blue</option>
<option value='Black' data-class='combo1'>Black</option>
<option value='Brown' data-class='combo1 combo2'>Brown</option>
<option value='Green' data-class='main'>Green</option>
<option value='White' data-class='main'>White</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
```

Complete code for generating this form:

```
my %all_colors = (
    1 => 'Red',
    2 => 'Yellow',
    3 => 'Orange',
    4 => 'Blue',
    5 => 'Black',
    6 => 'Brown',
    7 => 'Green',
    8 => 'White',
);

my @color_data = (
   { value => 'main', title => 'Main Colors', colors => [ 1, 3, 7, 8 ] },
   { value => 'combo1', title => 'Combination 1', colors => [ 2, 4, 5, 6 ] },
   { value => 'combo2', title => 'Combination 2', colors => [ 1, 2, 3, 6 ] }
);
my $html = "<fieldset>\n";
for (@color_data) {
   $html .= "<input type='checkbox' name='colorcheckbox' value='" . $_->{value} . "' id='colorcbox_" . $_->{value} . "' />\n<label for='colorcbox_" . $_->{value} . "'>" . $_->{title} . "</label>\n"
}
$html .= "</fieldset>\n<fieldset>\n<label for='colorselect'>Pick some colours!</label>\n<select name='all_colors' id='colorselect' multiple='multiple' size='" . (scalar keys %all_colors) . "'>\n";

for my $c (sort keys %all_colors) {
    $html .= "<option value='$all_colors{$c}' data-class='" . join(" ", grep defined, map { if (grep { $_ eq $c } @{$_->{colors}} ) { $_->{value} } else { } } @color_data) . "'>$all_colors{$c}</option>\n";
}
$html .= "</select>\n</fieldset>\n";

say $html;
```

Now that the form generation is out of the way, you can concentrate on writing the javascript! `;)`